# Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is Falseが解消できない。

Tags: python, 機械学習, pytorch

pytorchで推論をしようと保存したモデルを読み込もうとするとエラーが出てきます。
Google　colabの環境下で、gpuで学習を行い、CPUしかない環境下で以下のプログラムを実行するとエラーが出てきます。

```
model = Model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("185.pth"))
```

`model.load_state_dict(torch.load("185.pth"),map_location=torch.device('cpu'))`としてもエラーが出てきます。

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in validate_cuda_device(location)
    133 
    134     if not torch.cuda.is_available():
--> 135         raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
    136                            'device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. '
    137                            'If you are running on a CPU-only machine, '

RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

どうすればいいのでしょうか？
モデルの保存時は、`torch.save(net.state_dict(),'filename.pth')`で保存しています

---

追記

```
PATH ="193.pth"

model = Model
device = torch.device('cpu')
model = Model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location=device))
```

とコードを変更したところ、以下のエラーになりました。

```
TypeError: load_state_dict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state_dict'
```

もしかしてなのですが、Optunaで学習時に使用していたモデルのままではだめなのでしょうか？
[こちらのサイト](https://qiita.com/Yushi1958/items/cd22ade638f7e292e520)を参考にOptunaで学習させています。
ダメとすると、各ハイパーパラメータの値、関数を自分で入力してモデルを一度作成して、読み込むしかないのでしょうか？プログラムである程度自動的に各ハイパーパラメータの値、関数を入れることはできないのでしょうか？

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になるかもしれません。[SAVING AND LOADING MODELS ACROSS DEVICES IN PYTORCH](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/save_load_across_devices.html)

Comment: 元から使っている`Model`の内部が参照先 [2. Define and intialize the neural network](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/save_load_across_devices.html#define-and-intialize-the-neural-network) の`class Net(nn.Module):`と同等のものかどうかを調べてみてはどうでしょう？